# WordPress. Дубляж $_GET параметров в пагинации

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с такой проблемой:

При помощи функции **paginate_links** на моем сайте формируется пагинация. Мне необходимо в стоку запроса добавить некоторые параметры для фильтрации товаров. Например, http://site.ru/products/?filter=on&price_start=1600&price_end=9453

Когда я добавляю указанные параметры в адресную строку и обновляю страницу, ссылки в пагинации выглядят корректно:

- site.ru/products/page/2/?filter=on&price_start=1600&price_end=9453
- site.ru/products/page/3/?filter=on&price_start=1600&price_end=9453

и т.д.

НО, как только я перехожу на любую из страниц - к ссылкам в пагинации добавляется дубликат параметров:

- site.ru/products/page/2/?filter=on&price_start=1600&price_end=9453#038;price_start=1600&price_end=9453
- site.ru/products/page/3/?filter=on&price_start=1600&price_end=9453#038;price_start=1600&price_end=9453

Почему так происходит? Кто-то сталкивался с этим? Уже весь гугл перерыл, 2 день не удается решить данную проблему.

Код пагинации:

```
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999;
$html = '';

$paginate_args = array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'type' => 'array',
    'prev_next' => true,
    'prev_text' => 'Назад',
    'next_text' => 'Вперед'
);

$pages = paginate_links( $paginate_args );

if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var( 'paged' );
    $html .= '<ul class="pagination">';
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $html .= "<li>$page</li>";
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: И где тут дубликат? Было start-end, добавилось min-max. Мне кажется, рыть надо не Интернет, а ваш код. И пока вы его не покажете, вам тут никто не поможет.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не те параметры случайно скопировал - поправил ссылки, а также добавил код пагинации.